# Is it possible that a set contains two shared pointer to the same object?

Tags: c++, set, shared-ptr

In my code I have two vectors:

```
vector<lipid*> lipids;
vector<shared_ptr<bead> > ions;
```

The `lipid` class:

```
class lipid{
 public:
  lipid();
  lipid(double x, double y, bool up, int LID);
  ~lipid();
  void makeMe(int LID);
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> head;
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> body;
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> tail;
  int LID;
  vec direction;
};
```

And I generate the head, body, tail beads in the constructor of the lipid.

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> he(new bead);
std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> bo(new bead);
std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> ta(new bead);
this->head = he;
this->body = bo;
this->tail = ta;
```

Some of the lipids heads are inserted to the ions vector by:

```
vector<lipid*>::iterator lit = lipids.begin();
while (lit != lipids.end()){
  lipid * l = *lit++;
  if (l->head->charge != 0) this->ions.push_back(l->head);
}
```

where `charge` is an integer property of the `bead`. 
I also have a `map<vector<int>, set<shared_ptr<bead> > >` to store some of the beads named boxes. To add a `bead` into any of the map values I use:

```
bead b = l->head; //b white also be accessed through a beads vector that holds a shared pointer to all beads in the simulation
vector<int> t = b->getBox(); //a function that returns a valid box
boxes[t].insert(b);
```

In a specific part I have a set of shared pointer named `cBeads` and I insert to it beads in two, separate loops; the first goes over some of the boxes and insert into the `cBeads` set any bead that has bean changed and the other goes over all the ions and insert them.

I know that that a shared pointer is supposed to be the owner of the pointer or something, does this mean that I can place two shared pointer, pointing to the same object in a set?

I hope any of this make sense to you.

Comment: A shared pointer is a *shared* owner of a resource. Any number of shared pointers can share the same resource. Only when none are left will the resource be freed. (Did the question really have to be that long for that simple punchline?)

Comment: The question isn't whether multiple shared pointers can refer to the same resource, it's whether multiple shared pointers refering to the same resource can be stored in a `std::set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

`std::set` guarantees that it containes no duplicates. Whether an instance is a duplicate of another is decided by applying the second template argument, which defaults to `std::less`.

The standard library provides an `operator <` that operates on `std::shared_ptr`, performing a less than comparrison on the underlying pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Consult http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#comparison (or TR1, or the C++11 standard).

If two `shared_ptr` point to the same object, then they compare as equivalent under `operator<`, so they're duplicates as far as `std::set<shared_ptr<bead> >` is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

What is the comparison function you are using?  If it is the default (`std::less`), then you cannot have two pointers to the same object in the `std::set`; for that matter, I can't think of a possible comparison function which meets the requirements, and would allow it.

Comment: I suppose we can imagine that the comparison could somehow include the deleter. It would be broken to create two `shared_ptr` to the same resource with different deleters, but that's the user's problem rather than the set's.

Answer (score 0):

In general, think of a shared pointer as if it was a standard pointer as this is usually (I say usually to be conservative) the goal behind the shared pointer class.

Also, the notion behind shared pointer is definitely not about being the “owner” of a standard pointer but the opposite, ie: sharing the ownership amongst multiple participants.

Two different shared pointer instances (with the same pointee inside) should (will) compare equal, any other behaviour would be extremely counter intuitive.

If the use of the std::set was to restrict to unique entries, then it should perform as expected, however if you expect duplicates, you will need another container like a std::vector.

Hope this help